# Rails how to return single JSON object instead of array of JSON objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am limiting to 1, so I thought it would simple return an object in this case the same as `.find_by_email`

Code:

```
  # GET /users/:identified/type/:social_type
  # Returns a single record - so limit 1
  def find
    @user = User.where("identified = ? AND social_type = ?", params[:identified], params[:social_type]).limit(1)

    if not @user.empty?
      render json: @user.as_json, status: :created
    else
      render json: @user, status: :not_found
    end
  end
```

Current Response:

`[{"id":7,"voy_num":null,"voy_pin":null}]`

How can ensure I return a single `JSON object`?

Comment: `.first` with 'where' clause query will do the trick.  `@user = User.where("identified = ? AND social_type = ?", params[:identified], params[:social_type]).first`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the single object, use `first` with `where` like this:

```
@user = User.where("identified = ? AND social_type = ?", params[:identified], params[:social_type]).first
```